# Putting check box inside a label tag is causing issues with :before and :after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use a flipswitch like shown here:

http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/

The issue i'm having though is that I need to make these switches dynamically, so I can't set an id on each one (I'd also like to avoid doing this through javascript).

I tried putting the check box inside the label, however it seems that this causes the :before and :after on the "onoffswitch-inner" from the example to not work correctly. I'm pretty inexperienced with CSS and HTML, so I'm kinda stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just use class instead of ID...  problem solved

Comment: The `LABEL` element's `FOR` attribute is supposed to contain the ID of a "labellable element" or another `LABEL` which then points to a "labellable element" (see [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily fixed :-p I've set up a [demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcJuC/).

- Move the `INPUT` into the `LABEL`, making sure it appears before `<div class="onoffswitch-inner">`
- Remove `.onoffswitch-label` from the last CSS selector (it's in the middle of the selector…)

  .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + **.onoffswitch-label** .onoffswitch-inner {
      margin-left: 0;
  }

Comment: Yes durr  this is a fine idea. (the durr is for my silly answer)